# codeception doesn't builds helper files automatically

Tags: yii2, codeception

I have an YII2 application project with connected Codeception 4.1.8 testing framework (during the life of project before me there where made a lot of modifications).
So I tried to add my own method to the acceptance tester via adding to the tests/_support/Helper/Acceptance.php such a code:

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

class Acceptance extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function setRESTURL() {
        $this->getModule('REST')->_reconfigure(['url' => 'https://www.blabla.com']);
    }
}
```

-- but, after re-building of the acceptance tester (../vendor/bin/codecept build) and running a test with

```
$i->setRESTURL();
```

code inside I'm getting an error "[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method tests\actor\RegisteredTester::setRESTURL", so obvious that helper add-ons weren't included to the acceptance tester class.

So my question is - is there some ways to "switch on" the automatic including helper files to the codeception tester classes? (as far as I got they should be included by default but seems that in project where made some changes to exclude them in some way).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared your acceptance.suite.yml file, but you are asking for automatic inclusion, so I guess that you haven't enabled Acceptance helper in acceptance.suite.yml file.

It must look like this:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - REST:
            depends: Yii2
```

Comment: labai ačiū! :D
yes, that was the case - and also a little bit with namespaces (seems they where kinda changed in my company's framework)